# A regular expression for the strings in two sets of delimiters

Tags: regex

I have a text set as follows:

```
He found a &#compelling reason to get& out of bed in the #morning. | For reasons unknown, #most people &feel #compelled to& answer a ringing phone. | There's was no #logical basis for the choice since it was determined solely &on #intuition&
```

What I'd like to get is all the words with a # sign before it and surrounded by & signs: *#compelling, #compelled, #intuitions* (Not #morning, #most and #logical, which are not surrounded by & signs).

Any help would be gratefully appreciated :-)

Answer (score 0):

Would you try the following:

```
&[^&#]*(#\w+)[^&]*&
```

- `&[^&#]*` matches `&` followed by any characters except `&` and `#`.
- `(#\w+)` matches a word preceded by a `#` sign and the matched substring is captured in group 1.
- `[^&]*&` matches `&` preceded by any characters except `&`.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/3Ri5f8/1)

Although you are not specifying the regex flavor, it will work with many platforms.